# Using FindControl method of FormView within a Repeater

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, findcontrol

I need an advice how to correct my code. I am using FindControl method to find TextBox inside Repeater.  This is my markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1">
    HERE ARE SOME OTHER DATA
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:FormView ID="FormViewAddComment" runat="server"
             DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceInsertComments" DefaultMode="Insert"
             OnItemInserted="FormViewAddComment_ItemInserted" 
             OnItemInserting="FormViewAddComment_ItemInserting">
             <InsertItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddComment" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"
                     Text='<%# Bind("CommentText") %>' Width="200px" />
                 <asp:Button ID="btnAddComment" runat="server" CssClass="button"
                      Text="Comment" CommandName="Insert" CausesValidation="false"/>
             </InsertItemTemplate>
         </asp:FormView>  
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And this is my code behind:

```
Protected Sub FormViewAddComment_ItemInserting(sender As Object, e As FormViewInsertEventArgs)
    Dim FormView As FormView = DirectCast(Repeater1.FindControl("FormViewAddComment"), FormView)
    Dim Comment As TextBox = DirectCast(FormView.FindControl("txtAddComment"), TextBox)
    If Comment.Text = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

The Comment TextBox is not found and the code throws an Object reference error when it tries to access the Text property.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the textbox inside it using ItemDataBound event.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing `"txtAddComment`" which is there in FormView,then why are you finding FormView in Repeater and then again in textbox in that...you can directly find out it...

```
Protected Sub FormViewAddComment_ItemInserting(sender As Object, e As FormViewInsertEventArgs)
        If (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)      
            Dim Comment As TextBox = DirectCast(FormViewAddComment.FindControl("txtAddComment"), TextBox)
        If Comment.Text = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub
```

EDIT:-

My point is that you are writting the code in `ItemInserting` Event of `FormView`,so there you can directly find the FormView.I would suggest to use `NamingContainer` property in oredr to find the FormView which has trigged the event,by this way you can find the FormView then you can easily find the TextBox in it. 
There is example of NamingContainer for Gridview [Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1638799.aspx/1)

Comment: I am doing it like that because the page can not automatically find FormViewAddcomment as it can not find txtAddComment.

Comment: Yeah, I will try it in the evening

Comment: I tried it now and it doesn't work for me. I cant use `Dim button As Button = DirectCast(e.CommandeSource, Button)` because I can use only e.CommandArgument and not CommandSource